# How do hallucinations appear through reversing goggles?

Tags: vision, hallucinations

If one is experiencing elaborated visual hallucinations, what will happen when one puts on reversing goggles? Will hallucinations change their orientations as well? Links to relevant papers will be most welcome.

Comment: Interesting question...The idea of global precedence may be useful here. This question particularly reminds me of this idea in the context of [face inversion identification tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_precedence#Face_inversion).

Answer (score 5):

Karl Jaspers describes clinical reports in which patients hallucinatory perception was changed in accordance with the optical distortion. For example, a prism would double the images of devils, binoculars enlarge or decrease the image, colored glasses make it colored, etc. He refers "Seppilli, Contributo allo studio delie allucinazioni unilaterali. Riv. sper. di fren. 16, 82. 1890" and "Pick. Beitrage zur Lehre von den Halluzinationen. N. C. 11. 329. 1892" Now, the question is, has anyone done a study on that in the 20th century.

Comment: Have you tried following citations of those papers?

Comment: I'm afraid they're too old. I wasn't able to track them with Google Scholar / WOS.